# Using commas in a sentence that interjects "not" and continues with "but"

Tags: punctuation, commas

I have been struggling and googling to get the comma(s) right in the following simple sentence. Wherever I put it, it somehow seems wrong:

1. It's a war, fought not with firepower, but with access to historical records.
2. It's a war, fought, not with firepower, but with access to historical records.
3. It's a war fought, not with firepower, but with access to historical records.

Comment: I prefer a single comma after "firepower" or perhaps: "It's a war—a war fought..." // Is this war fought "with access to historical records" or "with historical records"?

Comment: Thanks DijnTonic,. Repeating the word war and adding a dash resolves my dilemma! It's even better in the original because I had an adjective before war and repeating it without the adjective gives it a rhetorical flavor!

Comment: You really shouldn't use any commas at all there. But you can keep the first one for effect: *It's a war, fought not with firepower but with access to historical records.* The use of a second comma incorrectly creates a nonessential element that breaks the sentence if removed: *\*It's a war but with access to historical records.* *\*It's a war fought but with access to historical records.*

Answer (score 1):

This can be punctuated without commas, although a comma before "but" is also used:

- "These days duels are fought not with pistols at dawn but with tweets and Instagram posts 24/7" *[New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/01/07/fashion/mens-style/feuds-soulja-boy-chris-brown-graydon-carter-donald-trump.html)*, 2017
- "increasingly, they are fought not with conventional weapons but with words." [Abstract](https://scholar.stjohns.edu/jovsa/vol4/iss2/5/) from *Journal of Vincentian Social Action*, 2019
- "But one top-secret U.S. Army battalion fought not with bullets but with stagecraft, using inflatable life-size tanks, phony insignias, soundscapes and fake radio transmissions to deceive German soldiers on the battlefield." *[LiveScience](https://www.livescience.com/wwii-ghost-army.html)*
- "the demonic is fought not with the hand of a healer but with accepting Jesus" *[Journal of Pentecostal Theology](https://brill.com/view/journals/pent/17/2/article-p157_5.xml)*, 2008

However we also find:

- "These latter conflicts are fought not with lethal arms or over territory, but through lobbying and over 'turf'" *[The Oxford Companion to Military History](https://www.encyclopedia.com/history/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/rivalry-interservice)*
- "The war against Israel is being fought not with tanks, planes or invading armies, but with words." *[Jewish Chronicle](https://www.thejc.com/lets-talk/all/singling-out-israel-is-a-very-modern-antisemitism-1.56516)*, 2016

Comment: I'm not sure how suitable the question is for ELU, but this is how to answer it wherever it belongs. Examples which have obvious respectability, and which show differing accepted practices. // I'd just add that if the fact that this really does qualify as a real war (though I can't see how it can be a literal war), << It's a war – fought not with firepower, but with access to historical records >> shows the needed emphasis on the initial statement.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that (3) is correct. *It's a war fought with firepower* doesn't need a comma. The 'not' phrase is the interjection that needs to be separated.